# Date prompt React.js component

Tags: javascript, datetime, form, react.js, react-native

I have created a date component (working GIF at the bottom; please ignore the styling).

There isn't a problem with the working of the code but rather the code I wrote seems messy and something hard for any other person to comprehend.

This is what I am doing: For the date Component in screen, I am creating refs and state like this

```
class OnBoarding extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.d1 = React.createRef()
        this.d2 = React.createRef()
        this.d3 = React.createRef()
        this.d4 = React.createRef()
        this.d5 = React.createRef()
        this.d6 = React.createRef()
        this.d7 = React.createRef()
        this.d8 = React.createRef()
    }
    state = {
        name: '',
        emailAddress: '',
        dob: '',
        male: null,
        female: null,
        keyboard: false,
        d1: null,
        d2: null,
        d3: null,
        d4: null,
        d5: null,
        d6: null,
        d7: null,
        d8: null
    }

dobHandler(number, flag) {
        const completeFlag = `d${flag}`
        this.setState({[completeFlag]: number})
        flag = flag + 1
        if (flag < 9 && number) {
            const nextFlag = `d${flag}`
            const textInputToFocus = this[nextFlag]
            textInputToFocus.current.focus()
        }
    }
```

And then rendering them like this

```
       <View style={styles.dob}>
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d1}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="D"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 1)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d2}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="D"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 2)}
                        />
                        <Text>/</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d3}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="M"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 3)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d4}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="M"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 4)}
                        />
                        <Text>/</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d5}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="Y"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 5)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d6}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="Y"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 6)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d7}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="Y"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 7)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d8}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="Y"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 8)}
                        />
                    </View>
```

The reason I have made so many `ref` is because the moment someone enters something in the current `textInput`, I want the focus to moved to the next one, which happens in `dobHandler` function.

Can someone help me in improving quality/optimizing and if this is the wrong way of doing it, then hint me on **how to achieve this alternatively**?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it correct – this is a perfect use case for refs and the state management is done equally well.
However, your code suffers from repetition and can be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ed up. A quick way to greatly reduce the amount of code and resulting complexity is to simply **use arrays**:

1. **Save the refs** in an array in *one* instance variable
2. **Store the current values** in an array in *one* state field
3. **Render the text fields** inside an iterator over one of them

A version of this, adjusted to the web / ReactDOM, might look like this:

```js
class OnBoarding extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dateFieldValues: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.dateFieldRefs = this.state.dateFieldValues.map(() => React.createRef())
  }

  setDateFieldValue(index, text) {
    this.setState(({dateFieldValues}) => {
      dateFieldValues[index] = text
      return {dateFieldValues}
    })
    if (index < this.state.dateFieldValues.length - 1) {
      this.dateFieldRefs[index + 1].current.focus()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.dateFieldRefs.map((ref, index) => (
      <input
        ref={ref}
        onChange={text => this.setDateFieldValue(index, text)}
      />
    ))
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<OnBoarding />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

*A library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#range) could be used to make the array initialization more readable, i.e. `range(8).map(() => null)`.*